# How can the CVR from a Cessna 560XL only contain old records and none from the fatal accident?

Tags: accidents, cockpit-voice-recorder, accident-investigation, cessna-citation

Is it possible that the CVR from a Cessna 560XL is just showing old records and nothing from the fatal accident when the plane crashed?

I´m talking about [the airplane crash in Brazil, where a election candidate was killed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Santos_Cessna_Citation_accident). The investigation team said that the data in the CVR contained only old data and they could not pinpoint from when those recordings were.

Comment: Curious and Cris, I know having your answers (comments really) deleted might seem at first glance to be (another) example of elitest control over this site. It is not. Cris' answer was not a fully thought out and fleshed out answer to the question, which could stand alone by itself. It was a comment. If you will register yourself, and participate, you will soon enough gain the points to be able to comment successfully. Cris' comment should be made into a comment to ratchetfreak's answer. A question's author can always comment on his own question, so curious should have done so on his question

Answer (score 12):

If the fuse was pulled between the previous flight and the crash then yes, the CVR can only record when it has power

Pulling the fuse or going behind the panel and cutting the wire will prevent it from recording.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have you ever heard of anything like that happening accidentally? Fuse blowing and noone noticing that on the maintenance checks?

Comment: But the pilots must do the check list prior to the flight and then confirm that everything is working.

Comment: @curious For one example case where the recorders only had old data, see [here](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/fulltext/AAB1301.html).

Comment: Recorders having old data can also happen if the erase head of a magnetic-tape recorder fails, resulting in an unusable mishmash of data from many different flights; for an example, see [here](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR0704.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

The FDR and CVR are not magical, they can fail. So can the components of the aircraft that feed them data.

E.g. if there were something wrong with the microphones in the cockpit, the CVR would not record anything being said there. At most it'd record static.
Same if there were a fault in the data cable feeding the data to the recorder (I assume most of those circuits are at least dual redundant, but at some point it all comes together in a single plug).

If the CVR isn't properly connected to the aircraft, it won't record anything.
This can happen, and it doesn't have to be some malignant act. A simple error in a maintenance procedure can do it.

It wouldn't be the first time a flight recorder holds no useful data.

There have been other instances where the events that eventually caused the crash themselves caused the data feed to the recorders to be interrupted some time before the crash for example.

Comment: "...doesn't have to be some malignant act."  I think you meant "_malevolent_ act", unless it was caused by a metastasising tumour.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone

Fight Data recorder(FDR) and CVR(Cockpit Voice Recorder) are both present on the Cessna 560XL; The statement made by the authorities could:

1. Be true. But for that to have happened, the airplane would have to have both Circuit Breakers(CB) pulled out by someone. When pilots conduct their pre-flight checks lights would illuminate indicating the problem. Or.....
2. It is indeed part of a cover up. Several witnesses said they saw one engine on fire before the plane went down. Having an engine fire during a go-around maneuver inside clouds is something extremely difficult and the flying pilot could have lost situation awareness and became disoriented.

Comment: Hello Antonio, welcome to Aviation.SE. Please see our [help center](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write good answers. Can you possibly provide sources and citation for some of your statements, such as the CB being pulled and the eye witness accounts?

Comment: Having an engine fire "during a go-around maneuver inside clouds is something extremely difficult" ... that sentence seems to indicate you think an engine fire could be/was set on purpose, care to rephrase?

Comment: If you believe the eyewitnesses, *every* airplane that ever crashed had an engine on fire -- even gliders.